# Python36 and sockets

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm connected to an IRC chat using socket.connec

I log in by passing my variables via socket.send

The log in is successful and then I sit in a while true loop using
Socket.recv(1024)

If I just continually print the response everything looks fine, but let's say I want to add to the end of the string... I noticed that socket.recv doesn't always get the full message (only grabs up to 1024 as expected) and the remainder of the message is in the next iteration of the loop.

This makes its it impossible to process the feedback line by line.

Is there a better way to constantly read the data without it getting trunked? Is it possible to figure out the size of the response before receiving it so the buffer can be set dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream-based protocol. Buffer the bytes received and only extract complete messages from the stream.

For complete lines, look for newline characters in the buffer.

Example server:

```
import socket

class Client:

    def __init__(self,socket):
        self.socket = socket
        self.buffer = b''

    def getline(self):
        # if there is no complete line in buffer,
        # add to buffer until there is one.
        while b'\n' not in self.buffer:
            data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                # socket was closed
                return ''
            self.buffer += data

        # break the buffer on the first newline.
        # note: partition(n) return "left of n","n","right of n"
        line,newline,self.buffer = self.buffer.partition(b'\n')
        return line + newline

srv = socket.socket()
srv.bind(('',5000))
srv.listen(1)
conn,where = srv.accept()
client = Client(conn)
print(f'Client connected on {where}')
while True:
    line = client.getline()
    if not line:
        break
    print(line)
```

Example client:

```
s=socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',5000))
s.sendall(b'line one\nline two\nline three\nincomplete')
s.close()
```

Output on server:

```
Client connected on ('127.0.0.1', 2667)
b'line one\n'
b'line two\n'
b'line three\n'
```

Comment: Tried checking each line to see if it ends with \n or ends with \r or ends with \r\n but none of the lines do. Even The complete ones. Tried checking before and after decoding utf-8. I wonder if my .splitlines() method is killing the new line character

Comment: @AntonioAnonymous Yes, `.splitlines()` removes the newline.  You have to buffer until you have a newline, then process the buffer.  I'll update with an example.